# scroll doesn't work with css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
          $(".navbar .navbar-default").css({"border-bottom":"1px soild #DDD !important"});
            });

        });
```

Why my above code doesn't work? I put an alert() within and try to scroll it worked. I want to show a border when the user scrolled down and hide it when it reached the top.

Comment: *"I want to show a border when the user scrolled down and hide it when it reached the top."* - So you want your code to do something conditionally, but you don't have an `if` statement...

Comment: @nnnnnn because the current css() already doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you provide valid css values.

There is no border property `soild` it should be `solid`

Try using:

```
$(".navbar .navbar-default").css({"border-bottom":"1px solid #DDD !important"});
```

The better approach for this is to use a css class and put your style in a stylesheet rule. It is simpler to undo by toggling of a class than it is removing inline style